# Change color of <td> if data found in table

Tags: css, angularjs, html

I am creating a web app in which I have a textbox:

```
<input type="text" style="height:30px; width:240px;" placeholder="Enter Data" />
```

... and a table which is fetching data from my webservice in an `angularjs` controller:

```
<table id="table" class="table table-bordered font" style="width:100%; margin-top:30px; background-color:white; padding-top:10px;">
            <tr class="bg-primary textalign">
                <th>Employee Name</th>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>To</th>
                <th>Month</th>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Reason</th>
                <th>Leave Id</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in sonvintable| filter:paginate" style="border: 2px solid #F3F3F3;">
                <td style="border: 2px solid #F3F3F3;">{{x.empname}}</td>
                <td style="border: 2px solid #F3F3F3;">{{x.from}}</td>
                <td style="border: 2px solid #F3F3F3;">{{x.to}}</td>
                <td style="border: 2px solid #F3F3F3;">{{x.month}}</td>
                <td style="border: 2px solid #F3F3F3;">{{x.year}}</td>
                <td style="border: 2px solid #F3F3F3;">{{x.reason}}</td>
                <td style="border: 2px solid #F3F3F3;">{{x.leaveid}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

This is how my data is displayed in my table:

```
Employee Name   From    To  Month   Year    Reason  Leave Id
Alpesh Renuse   26-02-2016  27-02-2016  2   2016    Personal    353
Alpesh Renuse   09-05-2016  28-05-2016  5   2016    Personal    402
Alpesh Renuse   07-09-2016  10-09-2016  9   2016    Personal    441
```

If a user enters `26` or `2016` or anything from the table, then the color of the particular `<td>` must be changed.

Comment: use `ng-class` and regex pattern to check the column value!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-class`:

First you need a CSS class with the color you need to change,

```
.change-color {
    color: yellow;
}
```

Then add a `ng-model` on your search `<input>`,

```
<input ng-model="searchWith" type="text" style="height:30px; width:240px;" placeholder="Enter Data" />
```

Then declare a new function in your controller:

```
$scope.search = function (feildValue, searchWith) {
    if (searchWith) {
        return (feildValue.indexOf(searchWith) !== -1);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Then add `ng-class="{'change-color': search(x.<whatever>, searchWith)}"`,

```
    <tr ng-repeat="x in sonvintable| filter:paginate" style="border: 2px solid #F3F3F3;">
        <td ng-class="{'change-color': search(x.empname, searchWith)}" style="border: 2px solid #F3F3F3;">{{x.empname}}</td>
        <td ng-class="{'change-color': search(x.from, searchWith)}" style="border: 2px solid #F3F3F3;">{{x.from}}</td>
        <td ng-class="{'change-color': search(x.to, searchWith)}" style="border: 2px solid #F3F3F3;">{{x.to}}</td>
        <td ng-class="{'change-color': search(x.month, searchWith)}" style="border: 2px solid #F3F3F3;">{{x.month}}</td>
        <td ng-class="{'change-color': search(x.year, searchWith)}" style="border: 2px solid #F3F3F3;">{{x.year}}</td>
        <td ng-class="{'change-color': search(x.reason, searchWith)}" style="border: 2px solid #F3F3F3;">{{x.reason}}</td>
        <td ng-class="{'change-color': search(x.leaveid, searchWith)}" style="border: 2px solid #F3F3F3;">{{x.leaveid}}</td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-class`

As, `ng-class` resolves angular expressions, you can directly write the logic in `ng-class` property. No need of a function even.

**Here is your required solution, start tying in the text field and check the color change.**

`Type: 2016, Compensate, Personal, 2015, Alpesh Renuse etc`

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.sonvintable = [
     {
        'empname': 'Alpesh Renuse',
        'from': '26-02-2016',
        'to': '27-02-2016',
        'month': '2',
        'year': '2016',
        'reason': 'Personal',
        'leaveid': '402',
    },{
        'empname': 'Alpesh Renuse',
        'from': '11-11-2011',
        'to': '15-15-2015',
        'month': '5',
        'year': '2011',
        'reason': 'Compensate',
        'leaveid': '403',
    },
    {
        'empname': 'Alpesh Renuse',
        'from': '12-12-2012',
        'to': '17-12-2012',
        'month': '6',
        'year': '2012',
        'reason': 'Official',
        'leaveid': '404',
    }
    ];
    
   
});
```

```css
.change-color
{
color:blue;
background: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">


<input ng-model="searchWith" type="text" style="height:30px; width:240px;" placeholder="Enter Data" />

   <table id="table" class="table table-bordered font" style="width:100%; margin-top:30px; background-color:white; padding-top:10px;">
            <tr class="bg-primary textalign">
                <th>Employee Name</th>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>To</th>
                <th>Month</th>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Reason</th>
                <th>Leave Id</th>
            </tr>
             <tr ng-repeat="x in sonvintable| filter:paginate" style="border: 2px solid #F3F3F3;">
        <td ng-class="{'change-color': (searchWith && x.empname.indexOf(searchWith) > -1)}" style="border: 2px solid #F3F3F3;">{{x.empname}}</td>
        <td ng-class="{'change-color': (searchWith && x.from.indexOf(searchWith) > -1)}" style="border: 2px solid #F3F3F3;">{{x.from}}</td>
        <td ng-class="{'change-color': (searchWith && x.to.indexOf(searchWith) > -1)}" style="border: 2px solid #F3F3F3;">{{x.to}}</td>
        <td ng-class="{'change-color': (searchWith && x.month.indexOf(searchWith) > -1)}" style="border: 2px solid #F3F3F3;">{{x.month}}</td>
        <td ng-class="{'change-color': (searchWith && x.year.indexOf(searchWith) > -1)}" style="border: 2px solid #F3F3F3;">{{x.year}}</td>
        <td ng-class="{'change-color': (searchWith && x.reason.indexOf(searchWith) > -1)}" style="border: 2px solid #F3F3F3;">{{x.reason}}</td>
        <td ng-class="{'change-color': (searchWith && x.leaveid.indexOf(searchWith) > -1)}" style="border: 2px solid #F3F3F3;">{{x.leaveid}}</td>
    </tr>
        </table>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

**Please run above snippet**

[**Here is a working Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/nTZ6JBPpVONtwzoQNzbs?p=preview)